# Phusion Passenger: Error executing action `restart` on resource 'service[passenger]'

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, passenger

I am using `Nginx+Passenger`.

I was trying to `upgrade Phusion passenger` from `5.0.29 to 5.1.11`. Everything was fine except restarting of the passenger is throwing an error as shown in the image.

[image]

I tried to again run the chef-client, its restarted properly. But I have to run the chef-client twice which I cannot afford.

Until the completion of 2nd-time chef-client, my website is down.

Recipes details:

```
service "passenger" do
  supports :status => true, :restart => true, :reload => true
  action [ :enable, :start ]
end
```

Any Idea why it is happening.

Thanks

Comment: Is chef telling passenger to restart or nginx? You should be managing nginx in your integration mode, passenger will be handled automatically by nginx internally. Can you check your nginx error log? It might be that there's an issue that's causing this during restart.

Answer (score 0):

Try invoking `/etc/init.d/passenger restart` and see the result. In case you get the same error, the problem is that it does not support that operation.

Also, as a workaround try notifying to the resource `stop start` instead of `restart`, it will do the trick.

Finally, do you restart the service on each chef-client run? Is this really needed? It will imply a small downtime every ~30 minutes

Comment: > I tried what you suggested. It's not giving any error. And for your information, restarting nginx have maximum downtime of 30 seconds, not 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

For me, failed restarts (after a passenger upgrade) was related to this [issue](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1990).

Try with downgrading passenger to 5.1.7 (or wait for the 5.1.12 release)